# unable to get updated cookie value in jquery after ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I have made a simple cart example in mvc. 
what I'm doing is , after clicking on `Add to cart` span , I'm calling a Controller Action method.

And then updating the cookie value with Total no of item in cart. but it give me initial value of cookie.

This is my Ajax Code to call Controller Action

```
   $(document).delegate('.addCart','click', function () {
            var getId = parseInt($(this).attr('id').slice(3));
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                url: '/Comments/CartDetailsSetGet',
                data: { Id: getId },
                success: function (data) {
                    var count = parseInt(data);
                    if (isNaN(count)){
                        alert(data);
                    }else{
                        var getCookies=  @HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CartCookie"].Value;
                        $('.cartNum').html(getCookies);
                    }
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("Error In Adding Item To Cart");
                }
            });
        });
```

There is `span > with class cartNum` in which I'm showing Total no of item in cart .

`addCart` is span on which I'm Clicking to Add Item In Cart.

This is my Action Method , which is My default Action

```
HttpCookie ck = new HttpCookie("CartCookie");
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (Request.Cookies["CartCookie"] == null)
            {
                ck.Value = "0";
                Response.SetCookie(ck);
            }
            IList<Comment> commentList = db.Comments.ToList();
            return View(commentList);
        }
```

This Action Which is getting called On Ajax Request.

```
static List<int?> CartItemsId = new List<int?>();
        public string CartDetailsSetGet(int? Id)
        {
              if (CartItemsId.Contains(Id) != true)
                {
                    CartItemsId.Add(Id);
                    int getCount = CartItemsId.Count();
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CartCookie"].Value = getCount.ToString();
                    ck.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                    var d = "";
                    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CartCookie"] != null)
                    {
                        d = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CartCookie"].Value;
                    }
                    return d.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    return "This Item Is Already In Cart";
                }            
        }
```

Here in `d` I'm getting updated cookie value but in Ajax Success , this line giving me Initial value, i.e 0.

`var getCookies=  @HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CartCookie"].Value;`

Comment: `var getCookies=  '@HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CartCookie"].Value';` is razor code and is rendered server side before the page is sent to the browser

Comment: @StephenMuecke: so what should i do to get updated cookie value on my view. so that even a user refresh the page even when he will see updated cookie value.

Comment: In your `CartDetailsSetGet` method you could return JSON containing the value(s) you want

Comment: @StephenMuecke: i can do this, but what if after adding some item, user refresh the page , then this method will not get called, and user can't see the total number, because as soon as he will refresh the page, My index Action will get called .

Comment: I'm confused by you code and not sure why your using a cookie. Could you not just store the current value in session and use that when the page is rendered (including updating the value in the ajax call so its current when the page is refreshed)

Comment: @StephenMuecke:in both case I need to return updated value through `JSON` if i will again use `razor` control to get value it will return 0.I just changed my Index Actionlike this
`if (Request.Cookies["CartCookie"] == null)
            {
                ck.Value = "0";
                Response.SetCookie(ck);
            }
            else
            {
                int getCount = CartItemsId.Count();
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CartCookie"].Value = getCount.ToString();
                ck.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
            }`

Comment: No I mean something like `public JsonResult CartDetailsSetGet(int? Id) { var data = new { itemCount = 2, message = "some message" }; return Json(data); }` Then in ajax success,`$('.cartNum').html(data.itemCount);`

Comment: @StephenMuecke: yes. this is good. Thank you very much .It works . You can Post answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you script, `var getCookies = '@HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CartCookie"].Value'` is  razor code and is parsed server side prior to be the browser. If you inspect the page source you will see that the value of getCookies is already set to "0".

Rather than trying to set or update a cookie, return JSON data in the `CartDetailsSetGet` that contains the values you want to render, for example

```
public JsonResult CartDetailsSetGet(int? Id)
{
  if (CartItemsId.Contains(Id) != true)
  {
    ....
    int getCount = CartItemsId.Count();
    var data = new { count = getCount , message = "some message" };
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
  {
    var data = new { count = null, message = "This Item Is Already In Cart" };
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
}
```

Script

```
$.ajax({
  ....
  success: function (data) {
    if (data.count) {
      $('.cartNum').html(data.count);
    } else {
      alert(data.message);
    }
  },
  ....
```